# for loop with two variable conditons

Tags: java, oop, for-loop

I got a question in my exam today about for loop with two variable(Question below ) 
why is the output of the code has one line when i am giving two System.out.println statements.

public class Loop {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0 , j = 0 ;j <  0 ; ++j , ++i ){
        System.out.println( i + " " + j);
    }
    System.out.println( i + " "+ j);
}
```

}

output:

### 0 0

Any explanation about for loop with two variables is appreciated.

Comment: If `j` is initialized to zero, will it ever be less than zero?  Will the loop body ever run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i starts off at 0. Condition requires j < 0. Loop never entered.

Answer (score 1):

The output line inside the for loop is never run, as the conditional statement, j<0, returns false since j is initialized as 0.

Answer (score 0):

You're never going into the loop, because your condition is `while (j < 0)`, and it's never LESS than zero, because it starts at zero. So all you're getting is the last `println()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Check you for loop condition

```
j <  0
```

and you initialized j with 0 so it will never be < 0. So your code never go into the loop, only initialize statement of for loop and  statement after the for loop is getting executed with the zero initialized at for loop value.

So you are getting 0 0 as output.